# Finding element via xpath with axes

Tags: xpath

I'm testing steampowered.com and I need to find  element on the form with condition that it has  descendant with text "Games".
It's that element below(it locates in the div with class "store_nav") and I'm using such xpath to locate it.

```
//div[contains(@class,'store_nav')]/div[descendant::a[contains(text(),'Games')]]"

<div class="store_nav_bg"> 
 <div class="store_nav">
  <div id="foryou_tab" class="tab flyout_tab" data-flyout="foryou_flyout" data-flyout-align="left" data-flyout-valign="bottom" onmouseover="EnsureStoreMenuTagsLoaded( '#foryou_yourtags' );">
  <div id="foryou_flyout" class="popup_block_new flyout_tab_flyout responsive_slidedown" style="visibility: visible; top: 42px; left: 0px; display: none; opacity: 0.245479;">
  <div id="genre_tab" class="tab flyout_tab" data-flyout="genre_flyout" data-flyout-align="left" data-flyout-valign="bottom">
    <span class="pulldown">
      <a class="pulldown_desktop" href="http://store.steampowered.com/games/?snr=1_4_4__12">Games</a>
    </span>
  <div id="genre_flyout" class="popup_block_new flyout_tab_flyout responsive_slidedown" style="visibility: visible; top: 42px; left: 131.667px; display: none; opacity: 1;">
  <div id="software_tab" class="tab flyout_tab " data-flyout="software_flyout" data-flyout-align="left" data-flyout-valign="bottom">
  <div id="software_flyout" class="popup_block_new flyout_tab_flyout responsive_slidedown" style="display: none;">
  <div id="hardware_tab" class="tab flyout_tab " data-flyout="hardware_flyout" data-flyout-align="left" data-flyout-valign="bottom">
  <div id="hardware_flyout" class="popup_block_new flyout_tab_flyout responsive_slidedown" style="display: none;">
  <div id="videos_tab" class="tab flyout_tab " data-flyout="videos_flyout" data-flyout-align="left" data-flyout-valign="bottom">
  <div id="videos_flyout" class="popup_block_new flyout_tab_flyout responsive_slidedown" style="display: none;">
  <a class="tab " href="http://store.steampowered.com/news/?snr=1_4_4__12">
  <div class="search_area">
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this xpath points on incorrect element(firepath shows even several elements). For comparison, this xpath works properly

```
//div[contains(@class,'store_nav')]/div[span/a[contains(text(),'Games')]]
```

What am I doing incorrect with descendant element?

Comment: Your XPath references a `store_nav` class value, but your markup has no such `@class` value.  Post a [mcve] or your question will be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[contains(@class,'store_nav')]
```

This will match the `div class="store_nav_bg"` and the `div class="store_nav"`nodes.

This Xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'store_nav')]/div[descendant::a[contains(text(),'Games')]]
```

will match `div class="store_nav"` plus all `div/span/a` elements you're after, because `div class="store_nav"` has a descendant of type `a`. 'Descendant' matches all descendants, however far down the hierarchy they are, not just the combination you're after. If you want only the `div/span/a` elements, you have to specify that.